# Include frametitle to top with section navigation

Tags: beamer, header-footer, frame-title

In the top left I have a navigation with the sections and I want to place the frame title on the top right instead of a new blue line. So far I have this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} % new 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\M}{\pazocal{M}}
\newcommand{\I}{\pazocal{I}}
\newcommand{\F}{\pazocal{F}}
\newcommand{\Se}{\pazocal{S}}
\newcommand{\E}{\pazocal{E}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Overview}\tableofcontents}
\end{document}
```

In the end I get this:

[image]

I want to move the title in the empty blue box on the top right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the frametitle to the headline is difficult, because at the time the headline is typeset, the frametitle is not yet know. However you could do the other way round and add the section navigation to the frametitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \leavevmode%
    \tiny%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \vskip-3ex%
    \hspace*{-\beamer@leftmargin}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil \quad \normalsize \insertframetitle  \vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\section{title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's ugly, but it works! Thank you :)